# If $A \subset B$, $B \subset C$, then $A \subset C.$ Is my proof valid?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

My Proof:

Let A = {$a_1, a_2, ... , a_n$}.

Let B = {$a_1, a_2, ... , a_n, ... ,a_m$}.

Let C = {$a_1, a_2, ... , a_n, ... ,a_m, ... ,a_q$}.

Then A, B, and C arbitrary subsets such that $ A \subset B $ and $ B \subset C $.
We can see that all elements in A are also in C. Therefore, $A\subset C$.

I think my proof makes sense but I feel like it's missing a lot mathematical rigours. But is this valid way to prove this? Am I missing something?

Comment: Are $A,B,C$ necessarily finite?

Comment: I have more difficult time with trying to prove this kind of problem, what I think seems to be a questions that speaks to itself. I came with a new proof that is in just pure English.

New proof:

B includes every element of A and every element of B is in C. Since A is part of B, A is also a subset of C.

Is this valid?

Comment: @user3000482 I would gladly accept that answer in pure English. Your instructor might want something more formal.

Comment: Since you have listed the elements of each set explicitly, there is no need to say "Then A,B and C arbitrary subsets". That doesn't really make sense. If you are trying to prove the more general statement in your title, no need to show the sets.  I think you really want to say "Let A,B and C be arbitrary sets with $A\subset B$ and $B\subset C$ then....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your proof assumes that each of the sets $A$, $B$, and $C$ are finite. A more robust proof might start like this: Let $a\in A$. Then $a\in B$ since $A\subset B$. Then what do you know about $C$?

Answer (score 4):

Hint. Don't try to write out the elements of $A$ - there may be infinitely many. Start with

Let $a$ be a member of the set $A$. Then I know $\ldots$ so then I know $\ldots$ so $a$ belongs to $C$. Therefore $\ldots$